# Remove records from DynamoDB periodically

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I want to remove records from my DynamoDB table in every 2 months counting from the record creation moment in the table. TTL would require me to use timestamp manually.

Is there a way to automatize a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TTL would require me to use timestamp manually

Not sure what you mean here. Adding a TTL value is by far the most optimal solution, as it deletes the items for free. Any other approach you would need to pay for reads and writes.

Simply adding a timestamp epoch value in seconds of `current_data + 2 months` will allow your data to expire naturally with no monetary or performance cost.

Comment: Records are written into the table in every minute. Would all the records have a specific 2 months time to live before they are deleted? This "current_data + 2 months" value should be updated manually as it cannot accept time functions.

Comment: Just add an extra attribute to each item, with a value of current_time+ 2 months. I wouldn't call that manual.

Comment: Ok now I get it. Thanks!